# Div screenshot in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, screenshot

I want to take screenshot of a Div Element in asp.net and save it to disk. I don't want to use  html2canvas library or html5 canvas element. Approach can be Server side or Client Side.

Comment: what do you hold in that div?

Comment: div contains some text and images...

Comment: Asking the visitors the take the screenshot and uploading it would not meet your requirements? :-P (just to be on the safe side)

Comment: let me give an example......consider omegle.......look at this link [link](http://logs.omegle.com/f1d8ace)...as you can see the chat is converted to an image...the same thing i want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but found this:

```
public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
{
    // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate(url);
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
    { 
        Application.DoEvents(); 
    }

    // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
    wb.Width = width;
    wb.Height = height;

    if (width == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
        wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    }

    if (height == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
        wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
    }

    // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
    wb.Dispose();

    return bitmap;
}
```

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-generate-webpage-thumbmail-screenshot-image.aspx

Comment: i have already gone through this code....it is a windows form based function as webbrowser class is present in system.windows.forms namespace...and to use windows forms in asp.net would be a bad idea...anyway thanks for the response...more suggestions are welcome :)...i am still confused how come omegle is doing the same thing...like this link [link](http://logs.omegle.com/f1d8ace)

Comment: You're almost definitely going to need a 3rd party. http://phantomjs.org/ seems to be the best supported. Only a single exe needed.

Comment: There are some threading considerations, but loading the WebBrowser control works just fine in asp.net. I've used something similar myself.

Comment: i will look into this thing....more ideas are welcome....does anyone has knowledge about omegle Div capturing technique?