# HTML to Thumbnail

Tags: asp.net, html, thumbnails

Is there any way to create image thumbnail from a specific HTML code,

For example: from a specific div and its nested divs (not the whole page)?

I reviewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php) however it's for a whole page screenshot not a specific HTML code.

My objective is to share it on Facebook since Facebook will only accept one image.

Comment: I want to clear your question. Do you want to make a screenshot of certain div only????

Comment: Duplicate Question ref  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840811/how-to-take-screenshot-of-div-from-a-webpage-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993535/div-screenshot-in-asp-net

Comment: You should have a look at [64bit-en/decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (binary-to-text & vice-versa)  and the HTML5 canvas. Here is for example, a plugin built on the html5canvas: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: yes exactly, i have div with background and content, i want to make a screenshot or image of these. my objective is to share it on facebook since facebook only accept one image.